# On the computation of $P(A \cap \neg B) + P(B \cap \neg A)$

Tags: probability, independence

Two archers shoot at a target.
A - the chance that the first archer misses 
B - the chance that the second archer misses
And we also have the probability that both archers miss the target
$$
P(A) = \frac{1}{5} \\
P(B) = \frac{1}{5} \\
P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{5} \\
$$
The first question is :
What is the probability that one archer misses the target.
What I did was 
$$
P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = ... = \frac{3}{5}\\
$$
I'm a bit stuck at the seccond part:
What is the probability that exactly one will miss the target 
$$
P(A \cap \neg B) + P(B \cap \neg A)
$$
I assumed that $A $ and $\neg B $ are independent and just multiplid:
$$
P(A) * P(\neg B) + P(\neg A) * P(B)
$$
But this is not the correct answer, what the teacher did was:
$$
P(A) - P(A \cap B) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)
$$
I want to know the rationament on how did the knew that this is the correct answer.

Comment: Please avoid uninformative titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) =\frac{3}{5}$$
computes (correctly) the probability that *at least* one archer misses.

You can write $A \cup B$ (at least one miss) as the disjoint union of three events: 
$$A \cup B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A) \cup (A \cap B)$$ 
interpreted as follows:

$A \setminus B$ ($A$ misses, $B$ does not miss);

$B\setminus A$ ($B$ misses, $A$ does not miss);

$A \cap B$  (both $A$ and $B$ miss).

To answer your second question (*exactly* one archer misses), you need to leave out the third term from the original computation. Thus,

$$P (A \mbox{ or } B, \mbox{ but not both}) = P(A \cup B) - P (A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A \cap B)$$

Also, note that you cannot assume independence here because the data contradict it: $P(A \cap B) \ne P(A) \cdot P(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

The events are *not independent*; as witnessed by the provided probabilities: $$\mathsf P(A\cap B)\neq \mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(B)$$
Therefore neither will an event and the complement of the other be independent.   Thus the product rule for the probability for intersection of independent events will *not* be applicable.

That being the case, one must look to other means to obtain what is sought from what is provided.   One other means on our toolbox is the additive rule for probabilities for unions of disjoint events (also known as the Law of Total Probability).   So is it applicable?

Well, can we express $\mathsf P(A\cap\lnot B)$ in terms of what we have using this?   Yes we can.
$$\begin{align}\because\hspace{7.5ex}\mathsf P(A)={}&\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap \lnot B)\\\therefore\quad\mathsf P(A\cap\lnot B)={}&\mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)\end{align}$$